# Combining some array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I'm kind of new to functional programming and I try to do the following: Let's say I have an array of values: `['a','b-','c']` and I want that every item which ends with a `'-'` is merged with the following array entry: `['a','b-c']`.

Of course I can do this by making a for-loop:

```js
var test = ['a', 'b-', 'c'], result = [];

for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
  var curr = test[i];
  if (curr.endsWith('-')) {
    curr += test[i+1];
    i++;
  }
  result.push(curr);
}
```

But how can one do this without the for loop?

Comment: I guess I would use reduce, but what's the problem with the for-loop (although I think there are some boundary-case issues with your code, like when the last element has a final dash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach (with `.reduce`):

```
var arr = ['a', 'b-', 'c'];
var trans = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (acc.length && acc[acc.length - 1].slice(-1) === '-') {
    acc[acc.length - 1] += cur;
  }
  else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Suggestion: `str[str.length - 1] === '-'`

Comment: Oh, now I see. `acc` is the array.

Comment: I like this answer as it doesn't use a closure.

Comment: What answer _does_ use a closure, then?

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, the way you programmed is probably the most efficient way to do this.

However, here's another option:

```js
var test = ['a', 'b-', 'c'],
    result = test.join().replace(/-,/g, '').split(',');

console.log(result);
```

This joins all elements into a string: `'a,b-,c'`, removes all occurrences of `'-,'` > `'a,bc'`, then splits the string back up into an array with the desired result, as you can see in the output.

This can be fool-proofed a bit, by changing the separator used in the `join` / `split`:

```
var test = ['a', 'b-', 'c'],
    separator = '||',
    result = test.join(separator)
        .replace(new RegExp('-' + separator, 'g'), '')
        .split(separator);
```

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple items with dashes, or if an element contains a dash followed by a comma, etc.

Comment: @torazaburo: Now it does ;-)

Comment: This solution won't work correctly if a value in the array contains a `,`.

Comment: @WillemdeWit: I updated the answer a bit. You can use any separator that works for you.

Comment: `...replace(/-\|\|/g, '-')...`

Comment: See, this answer has innate weakness; no matter which separator you choose, there might be elements in the source array containing this separator as a substring. Of course, it's possible to strengthen it a bit, checking all the array elements against it beforehand, but that makes the whole process cumbersome. Anyway, I like the technique in general - and the 'outside-the-box' approach too, so +1 from me. )

Comment: It is relatively simple to chose a short separator that will work in `> 99%` of use cases, though. Furthermore, the code is nice and short ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var test = ['a', 'b-', 'c'];

var result = test.slice().map(function (x, i, a) {
    if (x.endsWith("-") && a[i+1]) {
        var r = x + a[i+1]; // Join this and the next element in the array
        a.splice(i, 1); // Remove the next element from the array
        return r;
    }
    return x;
}).filter(function (x) {
    return typeof x !== 'undefined';
}); // Since the array comes back with a different length and some undefined elements, remove those. Thanks @Cerbrus for pointing this out

console.log(test, result, result.length); // ["a", "b-", "c"] ["a", "b-c"] 2
```

Comment: `result` will have trailing `undefined` elements, when you use `map`: `["a", "b-c", undefined × 1]`. This means `result.length === 3`. Also, `test` (ie, the input array) is modified.

Comment: Not quite. `result.length` is still `3`. Note that `console.log(result)` will not log the undefined element at the end of the array, but try logging the `length`, or just entering `result` in the console.

Comment: Using `a.splice` mutates the input array. Don't do that!

Comment: @Bergi: `a` is a copy of the input array. (`test.slice()`)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Oh right. Still horrible code :-/ And the `filter` doesn't work with falsy values, it should test for `undefined` explicitly

Comment: You can use `.filter(Boolean)` instead of `.filter(function (x) {return x;});`

Answer (score 0):

This way will work for multiple dashed elements in a row, and if the last element has a dash, uses `Array.forEach`

```
var test = ['a', 'b-', 'c-'], result = [], next = "";

test.forEach(function(curr) {
  if (curr.endsWith('-')) {
    next += curr;
    if (curr == test[test.length-1]) {
      result.push(next);
    }
 }else {
   result.push(next + curr);
   next = "";
 }
});
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Don't abuse `map` as a loop. If you don't want a result, at least use `forEach` so it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Another `map` + `filter` one. Most likely slower, as filter add's another iteration through the array, but works as the original does (which is probably not what the OP wants when there are multiple *-*'s in a row).

```js
var test = ['a', 'b-', 'c-', 'd', 'e'], result = [];

result = test
 .map((curr, i, array) => (curr.endsWith('-') && array[i + 1] !== undefined) ? curr + array[i+1] : curr)
 .filter((curr, i, arr) => (i>0 && arr[i-1].length > 1 && curr.length === 1) ? false : true)

document.write(result);
```

Comment: So, this returns the _incorrect_ result the OP's attempt also returns?

Comment: @Cerbrus I am not sure if OP wants to have ['a', 'b-c-d'] or ['a', 'b-c-' ,'c-d'] for ['a', b-', 'c-', 'd']. If it shall be the second case, then the above snippet is working starting point. I'd suggest using a `for` loop though, as it is most likely the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read all answers, so sry if I repeat sth. that has already been said.

Functional programming doesn't mean that there is always a predefined function that does exactly what you intend to; or a combination of some. 
Sometimes it is better to write a simple short utility-function than abusing the ones that are already there.

How about some "problems" like multiple dashed-values next to each other, or at the end of the list? How do you want to handle these cases?
This would be my implementation:

```
function combineDashedStrings(arr){
    var result = [], pending = ""
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var curr = pending + arr[i];

        pending = curr.endsWith("-") && curr || "";                 //multiple concats
        //pending = !pending && curr.endsWith("-") && curr || "";   //single concat

        pending || result.push(curr);
    }
    //pending && result.push(curr); //add last item if it contains a dash
    return result
}

combineDashedStrings(['a', 'b-', 'c-', 'd', 'e-']);
```

feel free to switch the commented lines/options

Comment: `return result` instead of `return arr`. Test your code before posting.